# How to export member formModule in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms

When i compile my code in cmd i see the following error:

> ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module
>   '"C:/Users/Amir_JKO/my-first-app/node_modules/@angular/forms/forms"'
>   has no exported member 'formModule'.

How can i solve this?

Comment: you will need to show us your code, its hard to guess without it.

Answer (score 1):

you are doing wrong import, try:

```
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
```

Comment: @amirkhazaie You wrote the first letter in lowercase

Answer (score 0):

import `FormsModule` in `app.module.ts`

```
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
```

Comment: if this is not work then you can install node module again
npm install